# When displaying website on mobile, it's zoomed in

Tags: html, css

I created this [webpage](https://www.rachelleanne.com) and whenever I view it on mobile it looks like this: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM9ew.png).

If I zoom out on the webpage then everything is visible. However I would prefer if it originally loads that way instead of having the user manually zoom out.

I have tried multiple things like:

- Changing the margins
- Changing grid-template-column sizes
- Ensuring there is no width with set value, only percentages

I have also added:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

And I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: one error i spotted in your css before going further: in your media query for 480px there is a semi-colon missing after position:relative; (it's just position:relative in your css)

Comment: The problem is the padding in your `.m-intro` element of 8em. Remove it or change it and you'll see the changes. Nothing is "zoomed" - it's stretched because of that one element.

Comment: Thank you for both of your suggestions. I will make the changes.

Comment: @Rachelle some phones are narrower than 480px, like the iphone for example (old ones 320, newer 375/414 ... lower than 480px doesn't display well still - perhaps investigate that. [Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) is a good tool for testing how your site will display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element overflows because its padding has a fixed value in pixels. Replace your padding in `.m-intro` by a value in percentage, so it will depend on the size of the container:

```
.m-intro {
    padding: 10%;
}
```